# How to capture blank return with AJAX & jQuery?

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, forms

I am trying to create a form in Django which accepts a code and searches the database for a matching row. If a match is found it displays the associated data in a form where some fields are disabled and some are enabled so that only certain fields can be updated. However, if a match is not found, I need the form to be displayed with all the fields enabled so that a new entry can be made.

Currently I have designed it the following way:
1) The first time the page loads, the JS doesn't do anything, and the page contains the HTML form.
2) The moment I type anything on my input textbox (which is not part of the form) the value is used to make a call to the URL specified in the JS file. That URL returns a form which has some of the fields disabled. It also gets the row from database which matches the value of the input textbox.
3) If the value doesn't match any row in the database, then the user is entering a new UPC code, which means he needs a form with all the field enabled. My problem is that the form is still semi disabled.
4) Also, if the user deletes the entire value from the input textbox I need the form to have all enabled fields just like the first page load had. But it still stays disabled.

I have come up with the following code.

**urls.py**

```
...
url(r'^get/product/(?P<upc>.*)/$', views.GetProduct, name='get-product'),
...
```

**views.py**

```
...
def GetProduct(request, upc):
    try:
        item = Item.objects.get(upc=upc)
    except Item.DoesNotExist:
        item = Item.objects.none()
    return render(request, "alpha/get-product.html", {'item': item})
...
```

**template**

```
<div class="container">
    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-xs-2" for="name">Name:</label>
            <div class="col-xs-8">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="{{ item.name }}" disabled>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-xs-2" for="qty">Current Quantity:</label>
            <div class="col-xs-3">
                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="qty" placeholder="{{ item.qty }}" disabled>
            </div>
            <label class="control-label col-xs-2" for="dp">DP:</label>
            <div class="col-xs-3">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="dp" placeholder="{{ item.dp }}" disabled>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-xs-2" for="qty">Add Quantity:</label>
            <div class="col-xs-3">
                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="qty" placeholder="Enter quantity to add to inventory">
            </div>
            <label class="control-label col-xs-2" for="mrp">MRP:</label>
            <div class="col-xs-3">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="mrp" placeholder="{{ item.mrp }}" disabled>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-xs-2" for="reorder_qty">Reorder Quantity:</label>
            <div class="col-xs-3">
                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="reorder_qty" placeholder="{{ item.reorder_qty }}">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-xs-offset-2 col-xs-8">
                <button type="submit" class="form-control btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(function() {

    $('#upc').focus();

    $("#upc").keyup(function() {
        var upc = $(this).val();
        if (upc == '') {
            upc = 0;
        }

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: '/get/product/' + upc,

            success: function(data) {
                $('#extra').html(data);
            },

            error: function() {
                $('#extra').html('Please enter valid UPC code.');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Currently, on first visit of the page the entire form is enabled and blank, if I enter a code that matched the database, the form displays the associated information and some of the fields get disabled just like I want. However, if I delete the entire code, the form doesn't get back to all enabled fields, the fields are still disabled and blank. Also, if I enter a new code, how can I display the a blank form instead of the semi disabled form?

P.S. I am entering the UPC code in a text box which is not part of this form. The textbox has an ID of 'upc' and the div that carries this form has an ID of 'extra' as you will see in the JS code.

Comment: You can call `form` reset DOM method, something like: `if(!data) {$('#extra form')[0].reset(); return;}`. That's said, i'm not sure how your template markup is related to your question. Looks like you'd have better to post MCVE

Comment: First time page load has a form with all fields enabled, however, after I type anything the JS loads the semi disabled form. That line doesn't change that I think. I added it to my code but it doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: But it's quite hard regarding your posted code to get your expected behaviour. If you want to reset a form, again, call `reset()` method on it

Comment: I have added a new paragraph to the question, maybe that will clear it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'error' event in your JS will not hit, because your view doesn't return an error.

I'm not 100% sure what you want, but you can return a 404.

**views.py**

```
def GetProduct(request, upc):
    try:
        item = Item.objects.get(upc=upc)
    except Item.DoesNotExist:
        return HttpResponseNotFound()

    return render(request, "alpha/get-product.html", {'item': item})
```

**template**

```
error: function() {
    $('#extra').html('Please enter valid UPC code.');
    $("input").removeAttr('disabled');
}
```

Comment: Sorry, the error function only pops up when I put space in my text box, other than that it doesn't show the message. So I don't think it will work. I want a new form when the code is unique and doesn't match any data in the database.

Comment: Thanks, I solved it by getting the logic inside the template. I know that's not appreciated so I'll try your code and get back.

Comment: Oh no problem I don't mind. As always, there are more solutions to the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the time you guys have put to this question. I have solved it. I built a logic in the template file like the following:

```
{% if item %}
    [ show form with some disabled fields ]
{% else %}
    [ show the same form with all fields enabled ]
{% endif %}
```

Thanks. :)